# ReactJS looping images using foreach error

Tags: reactjs, foreach, frontend

I am new to reactJS and I am currently working on a website with more frontend features.

I have a section that would display icons and I want to use a foreach loop in an external file so I do not have to keep on importing. I have tried this foreach below:

```
Icons.array.forEach((v) => {
                <Col span={v.colSpan}>
                  <div className="icon-container">
                      <img src={v.src} alt=""/>
                      <p className="icon-title">{v.label}</p>
                  </div>
                </Col>
              })
```

And here is my external file where I get my array of Icons

```
import React from 'react';


export const Icons = [
    {
        src: '../images/ICONS/Group 21@2x.png',
        label: 'Frontend',
        colSpan: 6
    }
]

export default {
    Icons,
}
```

I tried this one and react says it fails to compile saying it saw an expression 'no-unsued-expressions'

**UPDATE**

```
Here is my error:

      Line 12:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  10 |                 
  11 |                 
> 12 |               {Icons.map(icon => (
     |                     ^
  13 |                   <Col span={icon.colSpan}>
  14 |                     <div className="icon-container">
  15 |                       <img src={icon.src} alt="" />
```

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Col, Row } from 'antd';
import '../App.css';
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Icons } from './iconsarray'

export class Tech extends React.Component {
    render() {
            return (


              {Icons.map(icon => (
                  <Col span={icon.colSpan}>
                    <div className="icon-container">
                      <img src={icon.src} alt="" />
                      <p className="icon-title">{icon.label}</p>
                    </div>
                  </Col>
                ))}

            );
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you exporting Icons both as named and default export? Also isn't Icons already an array so you should use it as `Icons.forEach` and not `Icons.array.forEach`

Comment: Please try to use `lodash.sh`. It's very useful for this type of operation

Comment: Sounds like it could be a linting error. Are you declaring any variables anywhere that aren't being used?

Comment: @DragonBorn Unfortunately I got the same error when I tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your render method is expecting a parent element but there is no parent element in your render method.

Replace your render method with a parent element. I have added a `div` as parent for example.

```
 render() {
   return (
    <div>
      {Icons.map(icon => (
         <Col span={icon.colSpan}>
            <div className="icon-container">
              <img src={icon.src} alt="" />
              <p className="icon-title">{icon.label}</p>
            </div>
         </Col>
       ))}
    </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

To get/display each element, you need to use [Map ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) concept which returns element and forEach does not return anything.

```
   {Icons.map(icon => (
       <Col span={icon.colSpan}>
          <div className="icon-container">
              <img src={icon.src} alt=""/>
              <p className="icon-title">{icon.label}</p>
          </div>
       </Col>
   ))}
```

Comment: I made a demo and it did not give me any error regarding parsing or output related.

Comment: I misunderstood that you already had few things in render method and still got the bug. I made demo in my existing component. 
Thanks for up-voting.